# LibGdx inputProcessors touchDown is playing up

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

Hi so I have this ball that I am trying to keep in the air by using the touchDown method. This does work for me but its not consistent as I have to repeatedly tap the screen to get it to word and some times it just doesn't do anything.

```
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputController(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
            random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(2);
            Vector3 mouseCoords = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
            camera.unproject(mouseCoords);
            mouseCoords.scl(WORLD_TO_BOX);


            if(ball.getFixtureList().get(0).testPoint(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y)){
                movement.y = upPos;
                if(rand == 1){
                    movement.x = speedPos;
                }else if(rand == 0){
                    movement.x = speedMinus;
                }

                System.out.println("Reached the loop");
            }
            return true;                
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
            movement.x = 0.00f;
            movement.y = 0.00f;
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I have a class called inputController which is extending the InputProcessor so I can pick and choose which controls I want to use. I don't know if its just the gravity that isn't allowing the shape to move up or the code not firing when it is suppose to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now I figured it out. My box to world calculations were a bit off